# How to fill array list by different objects of the same class using stream API in Java 8?

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I parse some html by using Jsoup library. It has class Elements, that extends ArrayList and can contain collection of DOM elements. I get 5 different lists of elements by css selector like this:

```
Elements names = doc.select(".views-field-person-name");
Elements diplomas = doc.select(".views-field-markdiploma");
Elements special = doc.select(".views-field-mark1");
Elements english = doc.select(".views-field-mark2");
Elements full = doc.select(".views-field-mark");
```

And than I fill collection `students` by `Student`'s objects (have 5 `String` fields) like this:

```
for (int j = 1; j <= stateOwnedCount; j++) {
    students.add(new Student(
            names.get(j).text(),
            diplomas.get(j).text(),
            special.get(j).text(),
            english.get(j).text(),
            full.get(j).text()));
}
```

Is it possible to rewrite this loop by using Stream API in Java 8? Have no ideas.

Comment: What you have in place *without* stream api, is: faster, more readable and creates a lot fewer objects.

Comment: @Eugene Can you please explain how does my answer create more objects or is slower than what is done in the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could generate a stream of integers(would be indexes in your case), then convert it to a stream of student objects from it.

```
List<Student> students = IntStream
        .rangeClosed(0,stateOwnedCount)
        .mapToObj(j -> new Student(
            names.get(j).text(),
            diplomas.get(j).text(),
            special.get(j).text(),
            english.get(j).text(),
            full.get(j).text()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```